# pymsteams. I need to mention a person in message sent by pymsteams. How to do it?

Tags: python, microsoft-teams

I have installed and connected pymsteams to a channel and able to send messages. I read documentation but didn't find anything related to how to send message with mentioning a person as @me -> mentioning a person in a teams.

that's a beginning of my code:

```
import pymsteams;
myMessage = pymsteams.connectocard("webhookurl")
.... // here is a logic
myMessage.send()
```

Comment: Please go through this documentation of [User mention in Incoming Webhook with Adaptive Cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#user-mention-in-incoming-webhook-with-adaptive-cards)

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue thread on github requesting exactly this kind of functionality
https://github.com/rveachkc/pymsteams/issues/11

and there is a comment that presents a temporary solution, which is to manually modify the payload attribute of the connectorcard object. This worked for me.

```
teams_message = pymsteams.connectorcard(webhook)
teams_message.payload = {
    "type": "message",
    "attachments": [
        {
        "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
        "content": {
            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
            "body": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Hello <at>Leonardo</at>"
                }
            ],
            "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
            "version": "1.0",
            "msteams": {
                "entities": [
                    {
                        "type": "mention",
                        "text": "<at>Leonardo</at>",
                        "mentioned": {
                            "id": "leonardo.benitez@contorso.com",
                            "name": "Leonardo Benitez"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }]
}
teams_message.send()
```

The code snippet, thanks to [the author](https://github.com/LeonardoSanBenitez) for providing it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33556265)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the API provided by Teams and the capabilities of pymsteams, I encapsulated a method that can call others to send messages. You can refer to it.

```
import copy

from pymsteams import connectorcard, TeamsWebhookException

from typing import Optional, List

from pydantic import BaseModel


class MessageDTO(BaseModel):
    text: str
    title: Optional[str] = None
    mention_users: Optional[List] = None
    link_title: Optional[str] = None
    link_url: Optional[str] = None


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

DEFAULT_PAYLOAD_TEMPLATE = {
    "type": "message",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            "content": {
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "body": [],
                "actions": [],
                "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                "version": "1.0",
                "msteams": {"width": "Full"}
            }
        }]
}


class TeamsMessenger(Messenger):
    def __init__(self, webhook_url, messageDTO: MessageDTO):
        self.messageDTO = messageDTO
        self.my_messenger = connectorcard(hookurl=webhook_url)

    def send_message(self):
        try:
            # Init with message payload template
            self.my_messenger.payload = copy.deepcopy(DEFAULT_PAYLOAD_TEMPLATE)

            # Add title
            if self.messageDTO.title:
                self.my_messenger.payload["attachments"][0]["content"]["body"].append({
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "size": "Large",
                    "weight": "Bolder",
                    "text": self.messageDTO.title
                })

            # Add text
            self.my_messenger.payload["attachments"][0]["content"]["body"].append({
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "size": "Medium",
                "text": self.messageDTO.text,
                "wrap": True
            })

            # Add mentions
            if self.messageDTO.mention_users:
                mentions_entities = []
                mention_text = ""

                for mention_user in self.messageDTO.mention_users:
                    mentions_entities.append({
                        "type": "mention",
                        "text": f"<at>{mention_user.name}</at>",
                        "mentioned": {
                            "id": mention_user.email,
                            "name": mention_user.name
                        }
                    })

                    mention_text += f"@<at>{mention_user.name}</at> "
                self.my_messenger.payload["attachments"][0]["content"]["body"].append({
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": mention_text
                })
                self.my_messenger.payload["attachments"][0]["content"]["msteams"]["entities"] = mentions_entities

            # Add link
            if self.messageDTO.link_title and self.messageDTO.link_url:
                self.my_messenger.payload["attachments"][0]["content"]["actions"].append({
                    "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                    "title": self.messageDTO.link_title,
                    "url": self.messageDTO.link_url
                })

            # Send message
            self.my_messenger.send()

        except TeamsWebhookException as e:
            logger.error(f"An error occurred when send Teams message. {e}")

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"An error occurred when process sending Teams message. {e}")
```

reference

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cdesktop%2Cconnector-html#user-mention-in-incoming-webhook-with-adaptive-cards

https://pypi.org/project/pymsteams/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use an [AC card](https://github.com/rveachkc/pymsteams/issues/11). Here is a detailed [explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-cards) where I learned it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).